# Do I tip a bellhop for services other than transporting luggage?

Tags: usa, local-customs, tipping

I'm staying at a nice (U.S.) hotel for a conference. When I check out, they're going to let me leave my luggage there for a few hours until my flight in the evening. The concierge has informed me that I can take my luggage to the bellhop desk and they will hold it for me until I leave.

I know it is customary to tip a bellhop when they help take your luggage to your room, or help you flag a cab. But do I also tip for securing my luggage for a few hours?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tipping is discretionary but indeed there are many cases when it is expected. For this type of service, which I have used many times, I always give a tip. This is one case where you are depending on them and it is nice to show appreciation.

Personally, I see this similarly to a coat check. Once I get stuff I left back, I pay a dollar or two per item to compensate for the service, even though it was offered without cost.

Comment: Is there a rule of thumb for how much? I'm used to a % tip, but there's no fee for this service...

Comment: Usually $1-2 per bag. As usual with bellhops, they provide a service for free, so a percentage of zero just doesn't give anything.